# Cannot use variable as texture sample value - HLSL DirectX11

Tags: directx11, hlsl, pixel-shader

I ran into strange problem. My HLSL VS won't compile for given lines:

```
float2 finalUV = input.tex;
[branch] if(isHorizontal)
{
    finalUV.y += finalOffset * stepLength;
}
else 
{
    finalUV.x += finalOffset * stepLength;
}   
float4 finalColor = float4(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, finalUV).rgb, 1.0f);
```

But when I remove **finalOffset** variable - then it's compile fine and works. This HLSL code is actually part of FXAA shader based on http://blog.simonrodriguez.fr/articles/30-07-2016_implementing_fxaa.html

This code contains a lot of branching. I have no idea if that might be a problem. Here is my full HLSL code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: fxaa.ps
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Based on http://blog.simonrodriguez.fr/articles/30-07-2016_implementing_fxaa.html

Texture2D screenTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState SampleType : register(s0); 

//////////////
// TYPEDEFS //
//////////////
struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex: TEXCOORD0;
};

float rgb2luma(float3 rgb);

static const float EDGE_THRESHOLD_MIN = 0.0312f;
static const float EDGE_THRESHOLD_MAX = 0.125f;
static const float SUBPIXEL_QUALITY = 0.75f;
static const int ITERATIONS = 12;
static const float QUALITY[ITERATIONS] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Pixel Shader
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
float4 ColorPixelShader(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
//TODO - Pass as parameter
    float2 inverseScreenSize = float2(1.0f / 1280.0f, 1.0f / 720.0f);

    float3 colorCenter = screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex).rgb;   

//DETECT EDGES  
    //Center luma
    float lumaCenter = rgb2luma(colorCenter);

    //Direct neighbour luma
    float lumaDown = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(0, -1)).rgb);
    float lumaUp = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(0, 1)).rgb);
    float lumaLeft = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(-1, 0)).rgb);
    float lumaRight = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(1, 0)).rgb);

    //Find max, min luma
    float lumaMin = min(lumaCenter, min(min(lumaDown, lumaUp), min(lumaLeft, lumaRight)));
    float lumaMax = max(lumaCenter, max(max(lumaDown, lumaUp), max(lumaLeft, lumaRight)));

    //Delta (max-min)
    float lumaRange = lumaMax - lumaMin;

    [branch] if (lumaRange < max(EDGE_THRESHOLD_MIN, lumaMax * EDGE_THRESHOLD_MAX))
    {
        //Difference between lumas too small - there is no edge (or pixel is in very dark area)
        return float4(colorCenter, 1.0f);
    }
//CHOOSE EDGE DIRECTION
    //Find corners lumas
    float lumaDownLeft = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(-1, -1)).rgb);
    float lumaUpRight = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(1, 1)).rgb);
    float lumaUpLeft = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(-1, 1)).rgb);
    float lumaDownRight = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex, float2(1, -1)).rgb);

    //Combine lumas for future computation
    float lumaDownUp = lumaDown + lumaUp;
    float lumaLeftRight = lumaLeft + lumaRight;
    float lumaLeftCorners = lumaDownLeft + lumaUpLeft;
    float lumaDownCorners = lumaDownLeft + lumaDownRight;
    float lumaRightCorners = lumaDownRight + lumaUpRight;
    float lumaUpCorners = lumaUpRight + lumaUpLeft;

    //Calculate horiozntal/vertical edges
    float edgeHorizontal =  abs(-2.0 * lumaLeft + lumaLeftCorners)  + abs(-2.0 * lumaCenter + lumaDownUp ) * 2.0    + abs(-2.0 * lumaRight + lumaRightCorners);
    float edgeVertical =    abs(-2.0 * lumaUp + lumaUpCorners)      + abs(-2.0 * lumaCenter + lumaLeftRight) * 2.0  + abs(-2.0 * lumaDown + lumaDownCorners);

    //Check local edge direction
    bool isHorizontal = (edgeHorizontal >= edgeVertical);

    //Get lumas of pixels of opposite directions
    float luma1 = isHorizontal ? lumaDown : lumaLeft;
    float luma2 = isHorizontal ? lumaUp : lumaRight;

    //Calculate gradients for both
    float gradient1 = luma1 - lumaCenter;
    float gradient2 = luma2 - lumaCenter;

    //Check which direction is steepest
    bool is1Steepest = abs(gradient1) >= abs(gradient2);

    //Get strongest gradient and normalize it
    float gradientScaled = 0.25f * max(abs(gradient1), abs(gradient2));

//CALCULATE NEW UV
    //Calculate step length based on screen size
    float stepLength = isHorizontal ? inverseScreenSize.y : inverseScreenSize.x;

    //Average luma in correct direction
    float lumaLocalAverage = 0.0f;

    [branch] if (is1Steepest)
    {
        //Switch direction, because is1Steepest indicates DOWN or LEFT
        stepLength *= -1.0f;
        lumaLocalAverage = 0.5f * (luma1 + lumaCenter);
    }
    else
    {
        lumaLocalAverage = 0.5f * (luma2 + lumaCenter);
    }

    //Move UV by half a pixel to correct direction
    float2 currentUV = input.tex;
    [branch] if (isHorizontal)
    {
        currentUV.y += stepLength * 0.5f;
    }
    else
    {
        currentUV.x += stepLength * 0.5f;
    }

//FIRST ITERATION
    float2 offset = isHorizontal ? float2(inverseScreenSize.x, 0.0f) : float2(0.0f, inverseScreenSize.y);

    //Explore both sides
    float2 uv1 = currentUV - offset;
    float2 uv2 = currentUV + offset;

    //Read lumas from both extremes - find delta
    float lumaEnd1 = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, uv1).rgb);
    float lumaEnd2 = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, uv2).rgb);
    lumaEnd1 -= lumaLocalAverage;
    lumaEnd2 -= lumaLocalAverage;

    //If luma deltas is larger than local gradient - reached edge
    bool reached1 = abs(lumaEnd1) >= gradientScaled;
    bool reached2 = abs(lumaEnd2) >= gradientScaled;
    bool reachedBoth = reached1 && reached2;

    //If the side is not reached - continue exploration in given direction
    [branch] if (!reached1)
    {
        uv1 -= offset;
    }
    [branch] if (!reached2)
    {
        uv2 += offset;
    }

//CONTINUE ITERATION
    [branch] if (!reachedBoth)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            [branch] if (!reached1)
            {
                lumaEnd1 = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, uv1).rgb);             
                lumaEnd1 -= lumaLocalAverage;
            }           
            [branch] if (!reached2)
            {
                lumaEnd2 = rgb2luma(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, uv2).rgb);
                lumaEnd2 -= lumaLocalAverage;
            }
            reached1 = abs(lumaEnd1) >= gradientScaled;
            reached2 = abs(lumaEnd2) >= gradientScaled;
            reachedBoth = reached1 && reached2;

            [branch] if(!reached1)
                uv1 -= offset * QUALITY[i];

            [branch] if(!reached2)
                uv2 += offset * QUALITY[i];

            [branch] if(reachedBoth)
                break;
        }
    }

//ESTIMATE OFFSET
    float distance1 = isHorizontal ? (input.tex.x - uv1.x) : (input.tex.y - uv1.y);
    float distance2 = isHorizontal ? (uv2.x - input.tex.x) : (uv2.y - input.tex.y);

    //Get dinal distance with direction
    bool isDirection1 = distance1 < distance2;
    float distanceFinal = min(distance1, distance2);

    //Length of edge
    float edgeThickness = (distance1 + distance2);

    //UV offset
    float pixelOffset = -distanceFinal/edgeThickness + 0.5f;

//CHECK LUMA
    bool isLumaCenterSmaller = lumaCenter < lumaLocalAverage;

    // If the luma at center is smaller than at its neighbour, the delta luma at each end should be positive (same variation).
    // (in the direction of the closer side of the edge.)
    bool correctVariation = ((isDirection1 ? lumaEnd1 : lumaEnd2) < 0.0f) != isLumaCenterSmaller;

    //If the luma variation is incorrect, do not offset
    float finalOffset = correctVariation ? pixelOffset : 0.0f;

//SUBPIXEL ANTIALIASING
    //Weighted average
    float lumaAverage = (1.0f / 12.0f) * (2.0f * (lumaDownUp + lumaLeftRight)) + lumaLeftCorners + lumaRightCorners;
    //Radio of the delta between global average and the center luma
    float subPixelOffset1 = clamp(abs(lumaAverage - lumaCenter) / lumaRange, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    float subPixelOffset2 = (-2.0f * subPixelOffset1 + 3.0f) * subPixelOffset1 * subPixelOffset1;

    float subPixelOffsetFinal = subPixelOffset2 * subPixelOffset2 * SUBPIXEL_QUALITY;
    // Pick the biggest of the two offsets.
    finalOffset = max(finalOffset, subPixelOffsetFinal);

//FINAL READ    
    float2 finalUV = input.tex;
    [branch] if(isHorizontal)
    {
        finalUV.y += finalOffset * stepLength;
    }
    else 
    {
        finalUV.x += finalOffset * stepLength;
    }   
    float4 finalColor = float4(screenTexture.Sample(SampleType, finalUV).rgb, 1.0f);

    return finalColor;
}

float rgb2luma(float3 rgb)
{
    return sqrt(dot(rgb, float3(0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f)));
}
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings/errors?

Comment: No, there are no warning and/or errors.

Comment: @ivokabel Actually as I remember correctly, there was message like "expected a ')'" but there were no actual problems with parentheses.
I haven't checked it with newest version. I will and I will get back with message. I guess it will be similar. However as I was checking HLSL code on online compilers it worked fine. Both with PS_5_0 as well as PS_6_0.
I am using June 2010 SDK on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015.